# How to pass data from UserControl To Windows Form

Tags: vb.net

Window Form
I keep data in string XX and string YY then Window From close

UserControl
I need to get string value XX and string value YY after Window Form close

I don't know how to do

Comment: Have you ever used the `Text` property of a `TextBox`?  If so then you know how to pass data back and forth between a form and a control on that form.

Comment: You do it with something=UserControl1.Property where "UserControl1" is design name of your control and .Property is whatever property you want to get. For example UserControl1.Value, UserControl1.Name, UserControl1.Text...etc.